# why is the adress prefix for global unicast adresses in ipv6 considered 3 bits?

Tags: ipv6

global unicast adresses in ipv6  always start with number 2 or 3, but 2 or 3 takes only 2 bits , and the whole adress is represented in hexadec which takes 4 bits not 3, so why the prefix is 3 bits ?

[image]

Comment: L00k at it in binary, and you will see it is three bits needed to represent bot decimal `2` and decimal 3 to be unique from other possible numbers in the first nibble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first four bits (nibble) need to start with `001b`, ie. `0010b` or `0011b` in binary, or `0x2` or `0x3` in hex, with the first three bits fixed (2000::/3).